# Using strong tag inside li on a pug template

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I'm trying to use a strong tag inside an li on a pug template.
I'm rendering this page passing an Object called exercise:

```
ul
    li #[strong exercise.name]
    li=  exercise.name
    li= `${exercise.reps} reps`
    li= `${exercise.sets} sets`
    li= `${exercise.weight} kg`
    li= `Targeted muscle/area is: ${exercise.muscle}`
```

But I'm getting the following result:

```
exercise.name
Deadlift
8 reps
5 sets
80 kg
Targeted muscle/area is: Lower body
```

When I apply strong on exercise.name it makes only the string bold.
If I use " li- " I get (unexpected character '#') error.

Any way to do this without using a paragraph tag or css class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way to approach this would be to use the standard [string interpolation syntax](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-escaped). There's no need to use `=` and ES6 template strings.

```
ul
  li #[strong #{exercise.name}]
  li #{exercise.name}
  li #{exercise.reps} reps
  li #{exercise.sets} sets
  li #{exercise.weight} kg
  li Targeted muscle/area is: #{exercise.muscle}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code syntax a bit. Is this what you are looking for? If not, could you update your question and add the expected HTML output?

```
ul
    li
        strong= `${exercise.name}`
    li= exercise.name
    li= `${exercise.reps} reps`
    li= `${exercise.sets} sets`
    li= `${exercise.weight} kg`
    li= `Targeted muscle/area is: ${exercise.muscle}`
```

Comment: An `=` is needed after each element when using backticks for interpolation in Pug. Otherwise the HTML will include the backticks and not interpolate any variables.

Comment: @Sean Ops, I was testing it online and forgot to add them back. Thanks for the reminder.